# Jquery datatables isnt working in my application and I cant seem to figure out the problem

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, datatable

this is my view, i am generating a table with a section script part containing my jquery code. the table contains the info about users which i generated by consuming an api and deserializing the json into a list of driveusers

```
 @model IEnumerable<MyDrive.Models.DriveUsers>
    @{
ViewBag.Title = "DisplayApiUsers";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>DisplayApiUsers</h2>

<table id="myusers" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<tr>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)</th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.email)</th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.phone)</th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.phone)</td>
    </tr>
}
<tr><td>@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td></tr>
</table>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myusers").DataTable()
            });
    </script>
```

}

here is my shared layout which is used by my view and at the end of the file, the scripts are rendered by a bundle called lib which contains my jquery datatables files, and my jquery files as well as the bootstrap files

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fc9ddf8eee.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<style>
    .body-content .myFooter {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2.5rem;
    }
    .body-content {
        margin-left: 200px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
        @Html.Partial("_MyNavBar")
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
  
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lib")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

here is my bundle.config having 2 bundles the lib bundle as well as the css bundle

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/lib").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                    "~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js",
                    "~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"));
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Comment: Is the browser console giving you any errors?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:6484)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.10.2.js:671)
    at init.each (jquery-1.10.2.js:280)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:6481)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.10.2.js:671)
    at init.each (jquery-1.10.2.js:280)
    at init.DataTable [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.js:6156)
    at init.$.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.js:15095)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (DisplayApiUsers:224)
    at fire (jquery-1.10.2.js:3062)

Comment: Try removing your bundles and adding `<script src=...` tags directly - in the first instance to rule out the bundles

Comment: I solved the problem by adding <thead> and <tbody> elements in my table and making sure number of columns are all the same.

Comment: For future reference: here is the [installation guide](https://datatables.net/manual/installation#HTML).